# why object doesn't disappear right away

Tags: angularjs

Why dropping and object it does't disappear right away ? I have this peace of code, which deletes object, but it drops only after refreshing the page from web.

One solution would be refresing the page automaticly after deleting, is there any other solution ?

I guess with strings works like that, when using `splice(1,$index);`

drop is from my factory

```
app.factory('Inventory', function($resource, $http) {

    return $resource('http://someweb.com/api/v1/inventory/:id', {id: "@id"},
        {
            update: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {id: '@id'},
                isArray: false
            },
            save: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {id: '@id'},
                isArray: false
            },
            create: {
                method: 'POST'
            },
            drop: {
                method: 'DELETE',
                params: {id: "@id"}
            }
        }
    );
});
```

delete function

```
$scope.deleteInv = function(id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.info.objects.length; i++){
        if($scope.info.objects[i].id == id){
            Inventory.drop({id: id});
            break;
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: What does the `.drop` function do?

Comment: @qwertynl .drop is from my factory, doing DELETE method

Comment: Well we have no idea what it does...

Comment: @qwertynl sorry i added full factory description

Answer (score 0):

Even though your element is removed on the server side it is not yet removed on the client.

Try doing this instead:

```
$scope.deleteInv = function(id) {
    var scopeObjectsLength = $scope.info.objects.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < scopeObjectsLength; i++){
        if($scope.info.objects[i].id == id){
            Inventory.drop({id: id});
            $scope.info.objects.splice(i, 1); // REMOVE the element from client
            break;
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: ok, tnx for the tip, but seams not working with this example. Way do you use `i` and `0`?

Comment: @user3305175 sorry I made a typo. It should be `.splice(index, 1)` as I updated to. See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5767357/1022697) for the reason

Comment: hmm should i write `function(id,index)` ? And when i am deleting this should't I specify `index` in template `<a href="" ng-click="deleteInv(inventory.id)">remove</a>`